# Re-autoscaling an image in python matplolib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I experience difficulties in finding solutions to my problems in the Matplotlib documentation. Here is an example of a very simple problem. I am interested of course in the solution, but more importantly on how to find the solution in the official matplotlib doc !!!

I have an initially empty axes with autoscale off:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig= plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.autoscale(enable=False)
plt.show()
print ax.dataLim
print ax.viewLim
```

I get  0,1 limits both for the data and the view:

> Bbox('array([[ 0.,  0.],\n       [ 1.,  1.]])')
>   Bbox('array([[ 0.,  0.],\n       [ 1.,  1.]])')

Then I add an image that partly overlaps the initial view but also extends outside:

```
arr=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
im = ax.imshow(arr,interpolation='Nearest',origin='lower')
im.set_extent([0.5,2.,0.5,2.])
plt.show()
print ax.dataLim
print ax.viewLim
```

I get  the following limits for the data and view:

> Bbox('array([[-0.5, -0.5],\n       [ 2.5,  2.5]])')
>   Bbox('array([[ 0.,  0.],\n       [ 1.,  1.]])')

Now I changed my mind and decide to autoscale the data (and the view), expecting these limits:

> Bbox('array([[-0.5, -0.5],\n       [ 2.5,  2.5]])')
>   Bbox('array([[ 0.5,  0.5],\n       [ 2. ,  2. ]])')

I can't find a proper autoscaling scheme combining ax.autoscale(), ax.relim(), ax.autoscale_view, which reaches this goal.
For instance, the limits includes the data but are too large when using

```
ax.autoscale(enable=True)
ax.relim()
print ax.dataLim
print ax.viewLim
```

> Bbox('array([[-0.5, -0.5],\n       [ 2.5,  2.5]])')
>   Bbox('array([[-0.5, -0.5],\n       [ 2.5,  2.5]])')

The only very inelegant solution I have found is to redefine the image extent:

```
ax.autoscale(enable=True)
im.set_extent(im.get_extent())
plt.show()
print ax.dataLim
print ax.viewLim
```

> Bbox('array([[-0.5, -0.5],\n       [ 2.5,  2.5]])')
>   Bbox('array([[ 0.5,  0.5],\n       [ 2. ,  2. ]])')

Does anyone have a decent solution and can explain how I should have found it from the doc ?
Thanks.

Denis